# Getting 403 error from Firebase when trying to authenticate with Email/Password method

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

So what I have done so far is:

1. I have enabled **Email/Password** in **sign-in** methods in **authentication** in Firebase panel.
2. I have added the library and included the `google-services.json` file in my project.
3. I have used the code below to create a new account:

   ```
   mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "createUserWithEmail:failure", task.getException());

                }

            }
        });
   ```

And this is the error I receive:

> com.google.firebase.FirebaseException: An internal error has occurred. [ 403. That’s an error.Your client does not have permission to get URL /identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/signupNewUser from this server. That’s all we know. ]

So I got no clue how to solve the problem. Any further steps to take?

Comment: I don't know how your code can cause this problem, so you might want to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.